# $X_1, X_2, X_3$ i.i.d from $N(0,1)$. Calculate $P(2X_1 + X_2 + 4X_3 \geq 5)$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I figured out the distribution of $2X_1 + X_2 + 4X_3 \sim N(0, 21)$.
Then to find the Probability that $N(0, 21) \geq 5$ do we then need to divide the variance by $21$ to make it standard normal and then divide $5$ by $21$ so we really have $P(N(0,1) = 0.238095)$?

I am not quite sure what to do after finding the distribution.

Comment: Hint: If $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $\frac{X}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ is the _variance_ and $\sigma$ is called the _standard deviation._

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be distributed $N(0,1)$. You have the right idea except you are looking for  $P(Z \geq \frac{5}{\sqrt{21}})$, not $P(Z = \frac{5}{21})$.

At this point you can use a standard Normal table or software to compute the probability. Most standard Normal tables give the percentile for a given $z$-score. Using the table from

https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf

we get
$$ P\left(Z \geq \frac{5}{\sqrt{21}}\right) \approx P(Z \geq 1.09) = 1 - P(Z < 1.09)= 1 - .86214 = 0.13786.$$

Edit: Fixed the standard deviation!

Comment: Err, you have the right idea but the wrong numbers. What is wanted is $P\{Z \geq \frac{5}{\sqrt{21}}\}$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oops. Fixed it. Thanks!